# group theory dihedral group problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I am stuck in this problem. plz give some suggestion

Comment: What you tried?..

Comment: i only found 1st part.

Comment: I am stuck in your language use. Please use proper English to the best of your ability. This is a serious Q&A site, not some random forum on the internet. Also, please don't use images for critical portions of your post. These cannot be searched and as such detract from the value of the site as a knowledge repository.

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem:**     $D_{2n}=\langle x,y\rangle=<x>\ltimes <h>$, where $x,y$ are order-2 elements and $h=xy$ is an order-$n$ element, $h^x=h^{-1}$.

And it's a very common exercise question. (nothing special)

**$Attachment$:**
[image][image]